# The same model, multiple time in one view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, model

I would like make a pretty simple in my mind but really complicated when I tried to create. In a MVC ASP.NET environnement, I want to create one model but render it many times. It's work but when I want get back datas I have nothing.
The model look like this:

```
public class HardwareModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The wrapper look like:

```
public class WrapperModel
{
    public List<HardwareModel> HardwareList { get; set; }

    public WrapperModel()
    {
        HardwareList = new List<HardwareModel>();
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
readonly Hardware _hardware = new Hardware();
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_hardware.GetHardwareList(int.Parse(Session["idEmployee"].ToString())));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(WrapperModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

And the view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
<% foreach (var hardware in Model.HardwareList)
   {%>    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => hardware.SelectedHardwareType) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => hardware.SelectedHardwareType, hardware.Hardwaretypes) %>
            </div>
...
```

So the result is something like this:
[image: View Result]

The render is exactly what I want but the problem is that when I push a save button, the second part of the controller is used but the value of "WrapperModel model" is a empty List. In the Request value, I can see that everything is send to the controller but nothing match in the WrapperModel.

I don't know what to do because the number of "HardwareModel" can be 0 or 99 so I can't create HardwareModel1, HardwareModel2 ... like I read on web.

thanks for helping me and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an **EditorTemplate** and you will be good.

Create a Folder called **EditorTemplates** annd Create aa view (the editortemplate) with the name 
HardwareModel.cshtml

[image]

Now add the below code to the editor template (the new view). You may update the layout according to your requirement.

```
@model HardwareModel           
<p>
 Name @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) <br />
 Desc : @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description)
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
</p>
```

Now in your Main View, Use the `Html.EditorFor` HTML helper method to call this editor template.

```
@model WrapperModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{       
  @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.HardwareList)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />    
}
```

Assuming you have the GET Action sending a list of HardwareModels to the View like this

```
public ActionResult Hardware()
{
    WrapperModel model = new WrapperModel();
    //HardCoded for demo.Can be replaced with entries based on your DB data
    model.HardwareList.Add(new HardwareModel { Id=1, Name = "Printer", 
                                                     Description = "desc" });
    model.HardwareList.Add(new HardwareModel { Id=2, Name = "Scanner",
                                                     Description = " desc2" });
    return View(model);
}
```

Now your HttpPost action method will get the Child Properties on form submit

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Hardware(WrapperModel model)
{
    //check for  model.HardwareList Property here;
    return View(model);
}
```

[image]

[Here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9ABE38A81F442D6!192&authkey=!AKaRHDuYVqARlYM) you can download a working sample which i wrote to address your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried to do this right now and see what append.

Comment: This work great, thanks a lot. I have transformed your Razor synthax for my MVC2 architecture and everything work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best article that I have read on this issue. I hope it helps: [DotNetSlackers - Understanding ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx#s1-introduction)

Specifically, you might be interested in the section [Binding with a list of class types](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx#s8-binding-with-a-list-of-class-types)